# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-os

I'm trying to run sample `tkinter` a code but showing an error

this is the code that i tried,

```
def save_as():
    global fo
    fo = asksaveasfile(initialfile = 'Untitled.txt', defaultextension=".txt",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt"),("Word files",".docx")])
    print(os.path.basename(fo).split('/')[-1])
def sample():
    btn = Button(root, text='click', command=save_as)
    btn.pack()
root = tk.Tk()
sample()

root.mainloop()
```

But i geting an error like this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ismail\test.py", line 9, in save_as
    print(os.path.basename(fo).split('/')[-1])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ntpath.py", line 242, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ntpath.py", line 211, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper
```

can anyone help

Comment: @acw1668 sorry my mistake, i just edited now

Comment: Did you try to check what result you get from `fo`? (Did you try reading the documentation?) What result do you get? Do you think it makes sense to try to use `os.path.basename` on that result? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `fo` is an open file object, so you cannot use it in `os.path.basename()`.

Use `asksaveasfilename()` instead of `asksaveasfile()`.